# ASP.net C#, How to detect if the user on a phone or other mobile device is logged in on the wifi network

Tags: c#, asp.net

We need to detect if a student is on the premises to register attendance.

The method we want to use to determine if the student is on premises is whether or not they are logged on the wifi network at the campus.

This project is to allow an instructor to give the students an attendance code at the start of the class. The students will input the code into a asp.net c# web page, only if they are physically in the classroom.

What method can we use to determine whether or not the student is logged on the wifi network at the campus?

Comment: Just check the client IP? Access points give IPs in specific blocks. IP packets don't contain any information that would reveal what physical medium was used to deliver them.

Comment: I don't think you can get that info through any "API" on the device - it's not an app that's installed, it's just a webpage. Assuming that the server is running outside the school network, if the network has a static public IP (which sounds halfway reasonable) you could just make sure that the request to the server is coming from the school's IP address.

Another option could be to have some small service running on the school network, available only internaly, and write your site's JS to query that service - if it can get to it, it's on the school network. But any smart kid can bypass that.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was the location tech. Although, not sure how reliable if at all it will work for your purposes, since it deals with Triangulation. Some claim that it's accurate up to 3 feet away, while others claim 3 blocks away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS you can restrict access based on IP. Your wifi should have an internal ip (usually starts with 10.x.x.x). So rather than write any code into the registration app. Just restrict in IIS so only people on site can access the app.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, if we use that is there a way to show a redirect to an error page that the person trying to log on will see a message. "Not On Grounds!"

Comment: @Blocks It's been a while since I've done it but I seem to recall being able to specify the error type the user receives. From there it's just a case of pointing that error code to a custom `.htm/.html` file.